# Android Accessing image from another app when set as background image of a linearlayout get collapses when scorells

Tags: android

i am working in android on messaging app (let we call it app A) and want to access background image for message bubble from another app (let say app B). but all thing is going well but when i scroll the messages the bubble image of app A collapse which is accessed from app B. 
[You can see it in picture the image is collapsed from text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OQy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
the problem was in getting .9 pitch and converting it to drawable. which lose its .9 pitch form so when i try it by accessing it directly without converting it to drawable it become ok.